# Find words in strings which contain specific characters only

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write regex to find words which contain specific characters only.

For ex :

```
text= "I want to mes a message saying mess"
```

I want regex to find words which contain characters only "m" "e" "s" i.e mes and mess.

I don't want regex to find message as it contains other characters than "m" "e" "s".

`reg= r"(?:[mes"]){1,}` is what am trying....

Also can you please help me in writing a regex which contains words starting with me but does not contain words like men meal

```
text=" Regex should find mess mean and all words starting with me except men and meal"
```

**Output** should be only : `mess mean me`

Thanks...

Comment: You can experiment with regex interactively here: https://www.regexpal.com/ you might be able to come up with the right solution yourself

Comment: 1) `\b[mes]+\b` 2) `\bme(?!n\b|al\b)\w+`

Answer (score 2):

I think it is `\b[mes]+\b` but I think there are more ways to do this

Answer (score 1):

This my way,without regex

```
text = "I want to mes a message saying mess".split()
rtext = [t for t in text if t.find("me") == 0] # only find word begin with `me`
xtext = [t for t in text if "me" in t] #May be too broad
print(rtext)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Also can you please help me in writing a regex which contains words starting with me but does not contain words like men meal

Yes. try the following:

```
(?!(\bmeal\b)|(\bmen\b))\bme\w+
```

[see this link for explanation and demo](https://regex101.com/r/B2RFcE/2)